# Testing ARP poisoning in VBox NAT network

Tags: linux, virtualbox, nat, arp

I  wanted to test **ARP poisoning** in a **VBox NAT Network** environment. I currently have 2 VM in the NAT network: a Kali Linux VM (IP 10.0.2.15) and a *victim* Ubuntu VM (IP 10.0.2.4)

The other *victim* is the **gateway** of these VMs is 10.0.2.1 (corresponds to VBox).

When I do a host scan in Kali, I see both victims (10.0.2.1 and 10.0.2.4)

I was trying to check the **ARP cache** in the VMs of the NAT network, but I don-t get any info (IP/MAC) for the 10.0.2.1 gateway. I am using the command

```
$ arp -a
```

Is there a way to see the gateway MAC in the ARP cache of the VMs ?
VBox version is 5.0.2

Comment: I've configured the DNS client in both VMs and I see the gateway's info in the ARP cache now.

Comment: ARP Cache Poisioning attacks the Switch, not on the endpoints. The end systems tell the switch that they have a frame for a MAC, and let the switch decide which port to send it out, which is how you can MITM if you do it right. A end system doesn't know or care much about how that frame is delivered, so you can't attack it to get it to send the frame to an incorrect system. You could use an endpoint attack to DOS a link between two systems by screwing up the MAC-IP mappings, but you could not MITM or sniff traffic.